# Add-Type doesn't work on first run of a PowerShell script

Tags: sql, powershell, smo

I'm working on a powershell script which interacts with a local SQL Server 2016 database instance.  When I open the script in ISE and run it, it fails with an error: "verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded".  If I run it again immediately after, it works.

I'm currently loading the code like:

`Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken89845dcd8080cc91"`

but I've previously tried

`[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") and got the same results.`

I have also tried adding:

`start-sleep -s 120`

in case this was just an issue related to timing, but this has no effect.

I would expect that the assemblies would be loaded within a couple of seconds and then be immediately available. In addition to the "verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded" I'm also getting NullReferenceExceptions on the objects created from the missing assemblies.

Comment: I've seen issues like this before and it was usually a confusing program flow where Add-Type was not executed before the type was consumed. Can you post the whole script?

Comment: Add-Type is on line 1, so unless there's something I don't fully understand about the order of execution I can't imagine that's the case.  I need to redact some personal details then I'll post the entire script.  Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The correct and recommended way to load the SMO assemblies is to import the SqlServer module:

```
Import-Module SqlServer
```

This is included in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/load-the-smo-assemblies-in-windows-powershell?view=sql-server-2017)